# When a down voted question is deleted should the points to given back to user who asked the question?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, upvotes

I don't mean if anyone deletes it. But if the user who asks the question themselves delete it, should the down votes be taken back. or if a up voted question is deleted, should the up votes be taken back? Same goes for deleted answers and comments too. I tried deleting my down voted question and it says this wont give me my posting privileges back.

Comment: Is there a reason you believe reputation shouldn't be reversed in this scenario?

Comment: @animuson i have added the reason. see last sentence

Comment: Posting privileges are different than reputation. The automated post block still looks at deleted content, and if you have a lot of downvoted content, then just deleting it all isn't going to help you. *Reputation* is reversed shortly after the post is deleted, though.